Unity: How to display AppFlyer's SDK conversion data on the screen when a game starts?
I created a small game for android and now I need to use AppsFlyer to get and display ConversionData on a phone screen when the game starts in a working build. I've already installed and integrated the SDK, but I don't know what to do next. All I have is the dev key, I can't use AppsFlyer's account. Can I do something with that?
I've learned from official guide (https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/docs/conversion-data-unity), but the program just don't do anything.
My project with integrated SDK

Basically You need to build the apps to Android .apk (for example). Open the attribution link on your mobile device (check this to get attribution test link https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/docs/dl_android_init_setup#testing-uri-schemes), then install the apk. After that you can use or see the conversion data if you log it or show it on the screen.
Follow this page for more details https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/docs/testing-android

I believe for this method I need to register my mobile device for testing, for which I need an access to the AppFlyer account. And also I have to ask someone for an attribution link. I will ask if I can get help with that, but I don't believe it's a solution.

You never know if you don't try it. Maybe you can try by creating your own account for testing it.

In the end of the day, I just had to avoid this task. So we'll never know, if it was a solution.
